# Append tr's to tbody of existing table inside div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have existing table where I would like to add/append tbody element. Here is example of my HTML table:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <table class="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Last</th>
                <th>First</th>
                <th>DOB</th>
                <th>Nickname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript/JQuery code:

```
var divID = $('#myDiv table.myTable');
var tbl = "<tbody>"; 
for(var i=0; i < numRecs; i++){
    var jsRec = obj.DATA[i];
    tbl += "<tr id='lookup_"+i+"'>";
    tbl += "<td>"+decodeURIComponent(jsRec.ID)+"</td>";
    tbl += "<td>"+decodeURIComponent(jsRec.LAST)+"</td>";
    tbl += "<td>"+decodeURIComponent(jsRec.FIRST)+"</td>";
    tbl += "<td>"+decodeURIComponent(jsRec.DOB)+"</td>";
    tbl += "<td>"+decodeURIComponent(jsRec.NICKNAME)+"</td></tr>";          
}
tbl += "</tbody>";
divID.append(tbl);
$.alert(divID,'Main Menu',1000,600); //JQuery dialog box that takes html variable, title, width and height
```

I'm getting blank content in my dialog box with this code. If anyone can help or see where is my code breaking please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: can you do `console.log(tbl)` before `divID.append(tbl);`

Comment: This part of the code looks fine for what you're trying to achieve, it might be a problem with how you're getting your data.

Comment: Where is `numRecs` defined?

Comment: Have you debbuged your code?

Comment: it's defined above for loop. Num Recs is returning object after Ajax call.

Comment: I have debugged the code and I had undefined prior to my tr element. I have added tbody before and after the loop but still my table doesn't have css.

Comment: if `numRecs` is returning an object rather than a number, maybe you need to change the loop to use `numRecs.length`.

Comment: @espresso_coffee for undefined, you need to initialize the variable `tbl` like `var tbl = ''` before the `for loop`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're not closing the `<tr>` in your loop, making a series open-ended table-rows. jQuery validates HTML before appending into the DOM so it's likely silently failing when trying to `append`.

Comment: `jQuery validates HTML before appending into the DOM`...any explanation for this?

Comment: the closing `</tr>` is optional

Comment: Just my own experience - if you try to append an element without a closure, jQuery will auto-close it (though, horrible practice!)... but in the case of this code example, the loop creates N open `<tr>` elements with children `<td>` elements and no closure for the `<tr>`. I've gotten the same "blank" result from append in similar circumstances where the HTML was irreparable during append.

Answer (score -1):

I would separate the creation of elements in small chunks a shown in the following example. That way it would be easier to separate were things are going south. You´ll probably only need to replace `sampleData[i]["id"]` with `decodeURIComponent(jsRec.ID)`, etc. I only created the sampleData Array for the examples sake. It might also be possible to execute `decodeURIComponent()`  for each of the properties of your object inside a loop.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var sampleData = [{
      id: 1,
      last: "lst",
      first: "first",
      DOB: "IDK",
      nickname: "nick"
    }];

    var divID = $('#myDiv table.myTable tbody');
    var current, row, cell;


    for (var i = 0; i < sampleData.length; i++) {
      row = $("<tr></tr>"); //Create a row
      cell = $("<td></td>").html(sampleData[i]["id"]); //Create a cell
      row.append(cell); //Append The cell
      cell = $("<td></td>").html(sampleData[i]["last"]);
      row.append(cell);
      cell = $("<td></td>").html(sampleData[i]["first"]);
      row.append(cell);
      cell = $("<td></td>").html(sampleData[i]["DOB"]);
      row.append(cell);
      cell = $("<td></td>").html(sampleData[i]["nickname"]);
      row.append(cell);
      divID.append(row); //Add Row to the Table
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
td,
th,
tr {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <table class="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Last</th>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>Nickname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

At the end you might have trouble with `$.alert(divID,'Main Menu',1000,600);` but all you might need is to add a toString() or something like that.

Comment: I have tried this way and still I don't see any CSS on my table rows. Also there is no table tag.

Comment: What do you mean there is no table tag? Your trouble might actually stem from the `$.alert()` part. Why don´t you try replacing the bit of code I wrote within your $.alert(). It would also be helpful if you posted your console. Also use `console.log(divID)` before the append so see if jQuery or whatever you are using is finding the DOM object

Comment: I forgot to ask, how are you retrieving your data? since this might come into play, when estrablishing if it am asyn problem